# MDX how do you return the Average over a number of months

Tags: mdx

I've been looking at [AVG(MDX)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms146067.aspx) and would like to be able to get an average over a number of months.

Using this as a simpla MDX:

```
    SELECT NON EMPTY 
    {[Measures].[Freight]} ON COLUMNS
 ,NON EMPTY 
    {[Due Date].[Calendar Month].[Calendar Month].MEMBERS} ON ROWS
FROM [Adventure Works Cube];
```

It will return:

[image]

Is it possible to return:

```
    Freight
August  108567.2463
February    208635.5203
July    103180.7446
March   209712.7297
November    103873.3682
Avg Freight 146793.9218
```

I have tried:

```
WITH MEMBER [Measures].[Average Freight] AS
    AVG([Due Date].[Calendar Month].[All], 
        [Measure].[Sale])
SELECT NON EMPTY 
    {[Measures].[Freight],
    [Measures].[Average Freight]} ON COLUMNS
 ,NON EMPTY 
    {[Due Date].[Calendar Month].[Calendar Month].MEMBERS} ON ROWS
FROM [Adventure Works Cube];
```

It just returns:

[image]

Comment: You may not find this helpful but I'll advice you to leave this to the presentation layer. You can easily do that in Excel or SSRS.

Comment: I added an answer - you need to include a SET in the average function for the engine to average over...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do this you do not get the average:

```
WITH 
  MEMBER [Measures].[Average Freight] AS 
    Avg([Measures].[Freight Cost]) 
SELECT 
  {
    [Measures].[Average Freight]
   ,[Measures].[Freight Cost]
  } ON COLUMNS
 ,NON EMPTY 
    [Date].[Calendar].[Month].MEMBERS ON ROWS
FROM [Adventure Works];
```

The average is just the same as the actual measure:

[image]

To do an average you need a SET to do the average over:

```
WITH 
  MEMBER [Measures].[Average Freight] AS 
    Avg
    (
      [Date].[Calendar].CurrentMember.Children
     ,[Measures].[Freight Cost]
    ) 
SELECT 
  {
    [Measures].[Average Freight]
   ,[Measures].[Freight Cost]
  } ON COLUMNS
 ,NON EMPTY 
    [Date].[Calendar].[Month].MEMBERS ON ROWS
FROM [Adventure Works];
```

So the average measure now makes sense:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Below a tested example with Adventure Works. [msdn Avg (MDX) link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms146067.aspx)

```
 WITH  MEMBER [Measures].[Average Freight] AS
 AVG ([Measures].[Freight Cost]
)
SELECT
   [Measures].[Average Freight] ON COLUMNS,
  NON EMPTY   [Date].[Calendar].[Month].Members ON ROWS
FROM
   [Adventure Works];
```

Result

```
          Average Freight
July 2005       24067.9287
August 2005     51115.0148999999
September 2005  40996.0152
October 2005    33951.2746
....
```

Comment: the number in your results are just the same as `[Measures].[Freight Cost]`. The definition of AVG is located here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms146067.aspx. The first argument has to be a set.